# Bucket sort with huge random numbers

Tags: c++, bucket-sort

I know Bucket sort is has a lot of examples everywhere, so I tried to implement this so it can take huge random numbers with no luck

```
void Bucket_sort(int arr[], int max){
     const int maxsize = max;
     int bucket_list = new int [maxsize+1];
     int length = sozeof(bucket_list) / sizeof(bucket[0]);
     for(int i = 0; i <max;i++){
         bucket_list[i] = 0; //fill with zeros
       }
       for (unsigned int i = 0; i <length; i++){
           bucket_list[arr[i]]++;
        }
        int position = 0;
        for (unsigned int i = 0 i < length; i++){
           for(int k = 0; k<bucket_list[i];k++){
                arr[position++] = i;
             }
          }
       }
      int main() {
         int max = 50000
         int arr[max];
         for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){
            arr[i] = rand() % 50000;
            }
            cout<<"Here are the numbers before Bucker Sort"<<endl;
            for (int j = 0; j < max; j++){
                 cout<<arr[j];
              }
            Bucket_sort(arr,max);
            for (int k = 0; k<max; k++){
               cout<<arr[k];
              }
           }
```

some how I can't get it working, it will just out put the same order (unsorted)
I did find some same questions as mine, but none of them helped, here is one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037176/c-bucket-sort-putting-integers-into-buckets

Comment: This line ` int bucket_list = new int (maxsize+1);` doesn't even compile. First make sure your code compiles and that you do not mix C++ with Java.

Comment: @vsoftco That should compile, but won't do what the poster thinks. Instead it allocates a *single* `int` and initializes that to `maxsize+1`.

Comment: To the OP, turn on (more) warnings when building, it will tell you about things the compiler thinks are problematic. Also, getting the size of a pointer (e.g. `sizeof(bucket_list)` will give you the *size of the pointer* and not what it points to. Also, when positing code, make sure it *compiles*, copy-paste the actual code, don't rewrite in the browser as that might (and in this case had) add spelling errors that will distract from the real issue.

Comment: There are also other things with your code that stands out, like why have the `maxsize` and `length` variables to begin with? `maxsize` is just the same as `max` so can be dropped completely, and `length` is just `max + 1` so why not use that instead? If you declare `max` to be `const` the compiler will be able to optimize `max + 1` so it's only calculated once if that's what you worry about. And there's no reason to use arrays or pointers, not when you have [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
bucket_list = 0; //fill with zeros
```

this is changing your pointer, not filling with zeros. You should use

```
bucket_list[i] = 0; //fill with zeros
```

Edit: There are a lot more compiler issues with your code. Once you have those sorted out, the calculation of `length` is still wrong. You can't use the `sizeof` dividing trick, because `bucket_list` isn't an array. Replace

```
int length = sozeof(bucket_list) / sizeof(bucket[0]);
```

with

```
int length = maxsize
```

or just don't use length at all (you already have `maxsize`).

Comment: Even with that, I actually had it the same way you typed it, but I was too dump and typed the code in the browser which caused me to for get the brackets [] sorry for that

Comment: It worked for me, after fixing the typos, the `length` (as in my edit) and also the `bucket_list` definition to `int *bucket_list = new int [maxsize + 1];` as vsoftco mentioned in the comments.

Comment: yes, I have done the changes you suggested, and it compiles, and once I fill the array with like array[i] = rand() 500000; and pass 50 to the maxsize it give seg error

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void Bucket_sort(int arr[], int max){

     int maxsize = max;
     int *bucket_list = new int[maxsize+1];
    // int length = sozeof(bucket_list) / sizeof(bucket[0]);
     int length = maxsize;
     for(int i = 0; i <max;i++){
         bucket_list[i] = 0; //fill with zeros
       }
       for (unsigned int i = 0; i <length; i++){
           bucket_list[arr[i]]++;
        }
        int position = 0;
        for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++){
           for(int k = 0; k<bucket_list[i];k++){
                arr[position++] = i;
             }
          }
       }
      int main() {
         int max = 50;
         int arr[max];
         for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){
            arr[i] = rand()%50;
            }
            cout<<"Here are the numbers before Bucker Sort"<<endl;
            for (int j = 0; j < max; j++){
                 cout<<arr[j];
              }
            Bucket_sort(arr,max);
            for (int k = 0; k<max; k++){
               cout<<arr[k];
              }
              getch();
              return 0;
           }
```